# What's the lightest way to automate Selenium webpage navigation?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

So I've been thinking of the lightest way possible to run multiple different instances of a selenium process through the browser. Is there a way to "automate" a process  perhaps through the source code only without having to use additional resources to run other images, videos etc?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium headless browsing is the lightest way to automate selenium webpages.
A headless browser is a term used to define browser simulation programs that do not have a GUI. These programs execute like any other browser but do not display any UI. In headless browsers, when Selenium tests run, they execute in the background. Almost all modern browsers provide the capabilities to run them in a headless mode.